# Django, Pass QuerySet to url using redirect/redirect_to

Tags: django

How can I redirect from view to another url, passing my queryset to another view?
I tried this:

```
return simple.redirect_to(request, 'some_url', **{'queryset': results})
```

and this

```
return redirect('some_url', queryset=results )
```

but it does not work....

How can i do it?

Gabi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you expecting this to work? Redirection happens by getting the browser to request another URL. Anything you want to pass as a parameter to the redirection must therefore go into the URL you're redirecting to. It simply doesn't make sense to put a queryset into a URL parameter.

Presumably you could pass whatever arguments you used to get the queryset in the first place, but that's a lot of extra work.

Do you really need to redirect at all? What about simply calling the new view from your original one, and returning its response?